# jboss-serialization logger level not clear

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

I'm using Jboss 4.2.3 and I just went over jboss log4j properties and changed all jboss logs to ERROR level since In production I don't want a verbose server.log file.

I've noticed a comment in the file stating : "Limit the org.jboss.serial (jboss-serialization) to INFO as its ERROR is verbose"

I don't understand how is it possible that ERROR level is more verbose than INFO level?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, the message in mine is :
`Limit the org.jboss.serial (jboss-serialization) to INFO as its DEBUG is verbose`

Maybe a joke by a collegue ? Or certainly a typo in the version you got.

Comment: Its not a joke (as no one here has any sense of humor :) )

So I'm guessing it is a typo and it should be the opposite.